# dow process, oxidizing toluene to phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can  I bubble Oxygen thru Toluene to produce Phenol? Or do I need a catalyst?(Dow Process)

Before anyone says: "You can't"; google Wiki.

Comment: Can you just quote the relevant sections of Wikipedia instead of being defensive and telling us to go to Wikipedia before anybody even said anything?

Comment: I would like to note that according to the [so-named Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_process), the Dow Process has nothing to do with this question. The Dow Process either refers to the electrolytic production of bromine from brine or the hydrolysis of chlorobenzene with aqueous sodium hydroxide to form phenol. An analogous process for phenol production from alkyl benzenes is the [cumene or Hock process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumene_process) where isopropylbenzene is reacted with oxygen to form phenol and acetone.

Comment: Orthocresol I am Notr":"O the defensive"> I just got some scathing answers from Yahoo Answers, like":"It can't nbe done."

Comment: Ortho: I am Not:"on the defensive"> Look for the worst and yopu'll surely find it.

Comment: Ortho, I am Not:"on the defensive". Seek the worst and youll surely find it. On a Positive note; I just got a lot of scathing comments on YahooAnswers. like:  "It can't". T  he Wiki article is under Phenol. Or:  https:/wikipedia.org/phenol .  And its possible Wiki is wrong. They tend to be right on very technical subjects and with a ref. ref.

Comment: Here it is, Verbatum:  "Because of phenol's commercial importance, many methods have been developed for its production., 

oxidation of toluene, as developed by Dow Chemical:
C6H5CH3 + 2 O2 → C6H5OH + CO2 + H2O"                                         C6H5OH is Phenol, is it not?

Comment: Norris, it says: "production", Dow process, to C6H5OH, which is phenol, I believe. Perhaps article is oversimplified, misses a step, as I feared. Please describe this step and  google  Wiki, or , edit it. It says exactly as I quote. I am not running back-and-forth to prove it.Im not lying.

Answer (score 4):

Toluene oxidation is a two-step process.

According to *Ullmann’s Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry* (sixth edition), the first step is the oxidation of toluene with atmospheric oxygen to benzoic acid, which is carried out in the liquid phase at temperatures of about 100–150 °C and an absolute pressure of about 3 bar. A cobalt naphthenate is used as a soluble catalyst at concentrations of 0.1–0.3 %.

In the second step, the oxidation of benzoic acid with atmospheric oxygen and steam uses molten benzoic acid as the reactant and solvent at a temperature of about 230–240 °C and atmospheric pressure. Copper(II) benzoate is used as a soluble catalyst. Magnesium salts may be added to act as a promoter.

In this reaction, copper(II)benzoate decomposes to copper(I) benzoate and benzoylsalicylic acid (2-(benzoyloxy)benzoic acid). The copper(I) benzoate is regenerated to copper(II)benzoate with atmospheric oxygen. The benzoylsalicylic acid is hydrolyzed with steam to benzoic acid and salicylic acid (2-hydroxybenzoic acid). The salicylic acid is decarboxylated rapidly to phenol and carbon dioxide.